# Controlling entering WIT in stabilization branch

Tags: tfs, alm

is there a way to control which WIT (Bug; Requirement etc ) to be entered into the In stabilization branch? Shelving by developer and merging by admin can be a pain …

Comment: Do you mean which WIT can be associated to changesets in the stabilization branch? because WIT's themselves don't belong to any branch...

Comment: I relize this. Yet, I would like to have control about the WIT's (which have CS links) are affecting this branch code ...